# Is it possible to catch the absence of an attribute with css3?

Tags: css

I would like to know if we can catch these 2 differents cases avoiding javascript parsing:

```
<div class="a b"></div>
<div class="a"></div>

div.a.b {
  color: red;
}

div.a { //Specify "when there is no class b"
  color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With CSS3 you can use `:not`:

```
div.a:not(.b) { ... }
```

With CSS2 it's not directly possible, but but you can set the attributes you want and "unset" them with the `div.a.b` rule. You are already doing this: your divs are red, but "when there is no class `b`" they are blue.

Answer (score 2):

Using CSS3 selector:

```
div.a:not(.b){
  color: blue;
}
```

http://kilianvalkhof.com/2008/css-xhtml/the-css3-not-selector/